# Пытаюсь разобраться с виртуальным окружением в pyhon в vscode & pycharm, не подгружается

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

Создаю файл, например, app.py c содержимым

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from environs import Env
```

Пытаюсь создать виртуально окружение.

```
py -m venv _venv
```

Активирую

```
\_venv\Scripts\activate
```

Путь меняется на такой

```
(_venv) PS D:\
```

Т.е. виртуальное окружение подгрузилось.
Устанавливаю библиотеку

```
pip install environs
```

Установилась. Но в vscode и pycharm библиотека всеравно подчеркнута (не установлена).

Деактивирую, и снова активирую но результат такой же!
В vscode можно поменять вручную, еле нашел, но не удобно. В pycharm вообще не получается!

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: В vscode открывайте папку с проектом (Файл - открыть папку). Если установлено расширение Code Runner - снесите его или отключите, не используйте его для Python. В PyCharm открывайте также папку, если сам PyCharm не увидит виртуальное окружение, настроить интерпретатор из виртуального окружения в Settings - Interpreter settings (как-то так)

Comment: В PyCharm при создании проекта надо выбрать виртуальное окружение. Потом внутри PyCharm вызываете Terminal, и в нем pip install

Answer (score 0):

В общем как я понял виртуальное окружение в терминале отличается от виртуального окружения в самом pycharm, и, скорее всего (пока не проверил), в vscode. те если активировать виртуальное окружение в терминале _venv\Scripts\activate то в терминале все и будет работать, а вот дебаг в среде разработки pycharm так и будет считать модули не подгруженными.

Что бы их подгрузить нужно (я знаю 2 варианта)

1. правый нижний угол выбираем python 3.xx > add new interpreter > add local interpreter > location выбираем существующий __ venv
2. ctrl+alt+s > add interpreter > add local interpreter как и в предыдущем варианте

К сожалению, мне не удалось сделать так, что бы после команды _venv\Scripts\activate все это делалось автоматически. Именно это меня и интересовало.